# How to update value of array after pass that array to a function using Python's ctypes?

Tags: python, c++, arrays, ctypes

I create a DLL (TestDLL.dll) like below:

```
#include "stdio.h"

extern "C" {

typedef signed char     sint8;          /*        -128 .. +127          */
typedef unsigned char   uint8;          /*           0 .. 255           */
typedef signed short    sint16;         /*      -32768 .. +32767        */                              
typedef unsigned short  uint16;         /*           0 .. 65535         */
typedef signed long     sint32;         /* -2147483648 .. +2147483647   */
typedef unsigned long   uint32;         /*           0 .. 4294967295    */

__declspec(dllexport)
void pointer(uint8* seedVal)
{
    seedVal[0] = 12;
    seedVal[1] = 34;
    seedVal[2] = 56;
    seedVal[3] = 78;
}

}
```

And at python file, I write code like below:

```
import os
import sys
import ctypes
from ctypes import *

lib = cdll.LoadLibrary('TestDLL.dll')

seedVal = [10,20,30,40]
print(seedVal)
arr = (ctypes.c_int * len(seedVal))(*seedVal)
print(arr[0],arr[1],arr[2],arr[3])
lib.pointer(byref(arr))
print(arr[0],arr[1],arr[2],arr[3])
```

And this is the output:

```
[10, 20, 30, 40]
10 20 30 40
1312301580 20 30 40
```

=> My question: Why the value of arr not update value (12,34,56,78) of DLL file?

Comment: It is updated. Look: `10` and `1312301580` are definitely not the same number. Now why this value… check the exact types you use on both sides ;)

Comment: OMG. I change uint8 to int in parameter of function and it update value now! Root cause is from data type.

Comment: Aside: `print(list(arr))` is a shorter way to print the elements.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to answer my question:

- The output from python is not correct because the data type not match between ctypes library and c files (dll).
- Solution:

Change this code

```
arr = (ctypes.c_int * len(seedVal))(*seedVal)
```

To this code

```
arr = (ctypes.c_ubyte * len(seedVal))(*seedVal)
```

- Reason:

Follow https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html, "Fundamental data types".